# How common is Anaesthesia Awareness?

Tags: surgery, anesthesia

Anaesthesia awareness or intraoperative awareness is a situation in which the patient is partially awake during a surgery. How common are such incidences and what are potential problems associated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Previous** estimates were at 1 in a 1000 patients (1‰) suffer from intraoperative awareness:

> The medical literature suggests that in- traoperative awareness with recall while under general anesthesia may occur to some degree at a frequency of approximately 1 – 2 in 1,000 anesthetics. Most patients experiencing intraoperative awareness do not feel any pain.
>
> <sup>Source: American Association of Nurse Anaesthetists, [Patient Awareness Brochure](https://www.aana.com/docs/default-source/pr-aana-com-web-documents-(all)/patients/awareness_brochure0110.pdf?sfvrsn=801d49b1_4).</sup>

However, the 5th National Audit Project (NAP5) conducted a study on accidental awareness during general anaesthesia in 2014 [with the largest test group so far](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2014/09/140915114534.htm) **found that incidents were as low as 1 in 19.000 cases**. This huge project has been compiled into a book (with the chapters available as PDF here), below are just some extracts:

> [image]
> <sup>*Source:*   *5th National Audit Project of The Royal College of Anaesthetists and the Association of Anaesthetists of Great Britain and Ireland*: [Accidental Awareness during General Anaesthesia in the United Kingdom and Ireland.](http://www.nationalauditprojects.org.uk/NAP5report) **Report and findings of the 5th National Audit Project**, Chapter 6, p. 40. 2014</sup>

However, not all incidents were accompanied with pain or distress:

> The proportion of patients judged to have experienced distress at the time of the AAGA increased with Michigan score (Figure 7.5): distress was most common when pain and paralysis were experienced together, with 17 of 22 patients reporting distress (77%).
> [image]
>
> <sup>*Source:*   *5th National Audit Project of The Royal College of Anaesthetists and the Association of Anaesthetists of Great Britain and Ireland*: [Accidental Awareness during General Anaesthesia in the United Kingdom and Ireland.](http://www.nationalauditprojects.org.uk/NAP5report) **Report and findings of the 5th National Audit Project**, Chapter 7, p. 51. 2014</sup>

This means that of the on-average 0.0051% cases of AAGA, only 77% reported distress, and of those 77%, 80% experienced pain and paralysis, the sort of locked-in-experience that is presented in most newspapers.

The actual chance of such a locked-in-experience is thus 0.0031%.

As a comparison, below is a table of risks of lifetime-death by cause.
[image]

<sup>Values taken from: **National Safety Council**, [What Are the Odds of Dying From...](http://www.nsc.org/learn/safety-knowledge/Pages/injury-facts-chart.aspx), 2017. nsc.org.</sup>